# Calling a boolean vs. not equal to -1

Tags: javascript, boolean, equals, boolean-logic

I am working on a function that takes the domain name from the respective prefixes such as www, .com, etc. and am a little confused on what the difference between calling my alias to be true and calling the alias to not be equal to -1.

From a technical perspective, could someone help me understand why the not equal to -1 method works opposed to just calling the alias as true? (I may be butchering the question, so please correct my use of language)

I originally started with this, but it didnt work.

```js
function getDomain(url) {

  //create result
  let result = '';

  let searchWWW = 'www.';
  let searchHTTP = 'http://';
  let searchHTTPS = 'https://';

  let searchDOT = '.';
  let searchCOM = '.com';
  let searchCO = '.co';
  let searchRU = '.r';

  let indexOfStart = url.indexOf(searchWWW);
  let indexOfStartHTTP = url.indexOf(searchHTTP);
  let indexOfStartHTTPS = url.indexOf(searchHTTPS);
  let indexOfEnd = url.indexOf(searchCOM);
  let indexOfEndDot = url.indexOf(searchDOT);


  // if www 
  if (indexOfStart) {
    //slice from www to dot
    result += url.slice(indexOfStart + 4, url.indexOf(searchDOT, (indexOfEndDot + 1)));
    //if no www and no https
  } else if (!indexOfStartHTTPS) {
    //slice from https to dot
    result += url.slice(indexOfStartHTTPS + 8, indexOfEndDot);
  } else {
    result += url.slice(indexOfStartHTTP + 7, indexOfEndDot);
  }
  //return result
  return result;
}
```

This of the other hand, did work.

```js
  //create result
  let result = '';

  let searchWWW = 'www.';
  let searchHTTP = 'http://';
  let searchHTTPS = 'https://';

  let searchDOT = '.';
  let searchCOM = '.com';
  let searchCO = '.co';
  let searchRU = '.r';

  let indexOfStart = url.indexOf(searchWWW);
  let indexOfStartHTTP = url.indexOf(searchHTTP);
  let indexOfStartHTTPS = url.indexOf(searchHTTPS);
  let indexOfEnd = url.indexOf(searchCOM);
  let indexOfEndDot = url.indexOf(searchDOT);


  // if www 
  if (indexOfStart !== -1) {
    //slice from www to dot
    result += url.slice(indexOfStart + 4, url.indexOf(searchDOT, (indexOfEndDot + 1)));
    //if no www and no https
  } else if (!indexOfStartHTTPS) {
    //slice from http/https to dot
    result += url.slice(indexOfStartHTTPS + 8, indexOfEndDot);
  } else {
    result += url.slice(indexOfStartHTTP + 7, indexOfEndDot);
  }
  //return result
  return result;
}
```

Thanks for your help, looking forward to gaining a better understanding.

Comment: All numbers, other than 0, are truthy.  `-1` is a truthy number.  So changing it from just `if (thatVariable)` to `if (thatVariable !== -1)` changes the behavior of when it does or does not go in that if statement

Comment: more importantly `indexOf()` returns -1 when the search string is not found so specifically testing for it makes the most sense

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, both points made this much more clear. I didn't consider the fact that truthy would change the behavior, and testing for indexOf() -1 native functionality makes the most sense.